# AngularJS : undefined is not a function from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have multiple functions inside of my factory and I cannot call my saveCharacter function from a button click using ng-click. The getCharacters function works just fine. Sorry in advance for the repost, I have gone over many different examples and cannot solve my particular issue with those. I can see my functions when I log the xmlService, but i'm not sure why it won't call to it. I was trying to return a post to a PHP file in saveCharacter, but changed to a string return to try to test to see what my issue was.

Thanks again for any help.

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('arena', []);

app.factory('xmlService', function($http){

    var factory = {};

    factory.getCharacter = function getCharacter(){         
        return $http.get('xml/characterTemplate.xml');
    };
    factory.saveCharacter = function saveCharacter(){
        return "hello";
        //return $http.post('php/crud.php');
    };

    return factory;

});

app.controller('FighterController', ['$scope','xmlService', function($scope, xmlService){
    this.fighterList = fighterList;


    $scope.saveFighter = function saveFighter(){
        console.log(xmlService);
        xmlService.saveCharacter.success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    function loadFighters(){


        xmlService.getCharacter().success(function(data){
            var x2js = new X2JS(); 
            var charactersList  = x2js.xml_str2json(data);

            for(var i = 0; i < charactersList.characters.character.length; i++)
            {
                var currentFighter = charactersList.characters.character[i];
                fighterList.push(currentFighter);

            }                
            $scope.FighterController = charactersList;
        });
    }
    loadFighters();
}]);



var fighterList = [
];

})();
```

Other questions I had while writing my first Angular app, what is the point of the code:

```
$scope.FighterController = charactersList;
```

does that allow me to access the returned data on the view side? do I have to reset the scope in my saveFighter function to cause my button to work?

Am I setting the dependencies correctly for my app.controller, and is that dependency injection?

Thank you all, and any comments on how my code is setup are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really *explained* what you did to fix this issue, so I'll explain it.

Here, you are trying to call `xmlService.saveCharacter.success()`:

```
xmlService.saveCharacter.success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

But `xmlService.saveCharacter` is a function. It has no `success` property; `success` is undefined. So this gives the error you were seeing.

You need to *call* `xmlService.saveCharacter()`:

```
xmlService.saveCharacter().success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

But this is still a problem because the `saveCharacter()` function returns the string `"hello"`. This string doesn't have a `success` property. Yet again `success` is `undefined`, so now that causes the same error.

To fix that error, you just need to remove the `return "hello";` and uncomment the code you had commented out:

```
factory.saveCharacter = function saveCharacter(){
    return $http.post('php/crud.php');
};
```

Fixing those two problems should remedy your issue.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly it, i'll totally vote your answer as correct. I had to add the $http.post return, and correct the missing parenthesis. I wish you came here in the morning though to tell me lol. Oh well had time to play with my dog and think about the problem. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing invoking a function with `()` change code to:

```
$scope.saveFighter = function saveFighter(){
    console.log(xmlService);

    xmlService.saveCharacter().success(function(data){
    // ----------------------^
        console.log(data);
    });
 }
```

`$scope.FighterController = charactersList;`is assigning data of characterList to scope variable and scope variable are accessible in html scope is like a bridge between controller and views.

I recommend you to [start reading angularjs](http://goo.gl/MMPPJ3)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've added the () to my function that I missed, but I still receive an undefined is not a function error.

I've been doing reading but this tutorial is a new one, so thank you for the link i'll start reading.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted my factory to this structure and now I can call my functions.

```
app.factory('xmlService', function($http){

    var factory = {
        getCharacter: function(){
            return $http.get('xml/characterTemplate.xml');
        },
        saveCharacter:function(){
            console.log('hello?');
            return $http.post('php/crud.php');
        }
    };
    return factory;

});
```

in my controller

```
$scope.saveFighter = function(){
        console.log(xmlService);
        xmlService.saveCharacter().success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    }

    function loadFighters(){
        xmlService.getCharacter().success(function(data){
            var x2js = new X2JS(); 
            var charactersList  = x2js.xml_str2json(data);

            for(var i = 0; i < charactersList.characters.character.length; i++)
            {
                var currentFighter = charactersList.characters.character[i];
                fighterList.push(currentFighter);

            }                
            $scope.FighterController = charactersList;
        });
    }
    loadFighters();
```